# How to resolve this: "NuGet Package restore failed for project VTS: Unable to find version '10.0.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common'"?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, rdlc, reportviewer

I am using VS 2013 for a webform project. But when adding a rdlc report I am getting the below message

> "NuGet Package restore failed for project VTS: Unable to find version
> '10.0.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common'.."

[image]

I tried every possible way to dowload version 10.0.0.0; Unfortunately I failed every time. I have installed reportviewer2010 &reportviewer 2015 runtime.

In .aspx page I added this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

and in webconfig file

```
<!--<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
  </assemblies>-->
```

Nuget package has no dll with Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common 10.0.0.0; There is only one version available i.e Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common 10.0.40219.1;

[image]

Comment: webconfig file<assemblies>
    
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </assemblies>

Comment: Please read and apply: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/11107541). Set the right expectation for yourself that [you may need to wait patiently for an answer](/help/no-one-answers).